# Finding voltages in a circuit with current source

Tags: voltage, resistors, current-source

I am trying to understand the basics of current source, but I don't know how to calculate the voltages v1 and v2. I tried to sketch the expression for current divider, but I think I didn't actually understood how to use it properly on an exercise.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG3nT1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Try finding the equivalent resistance of everything and finding the voltage. Then work backwards. Find the voltage divider voltage of R1 and the equivalent resistance of the rest of the circuit and keep expanding from there.

Comment: Thank you!! It worked perfectly. But the texbook I am using has a different way to calculate v2: first of all it finds the Req of R3 and R4, then the current on the 30 ohms resistor (i = (25)*(75) / (125)) and finally it affirms that v2 = Req * i. How did he find this current i???

Comment: I can't defend the book's methods. It might be in line with a [lie-to-children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children) the book told earlier.

Comment: @ViníciusLopesSimões, That's probably using the current divider rule. (the dual of the voltage divider rule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the current through the R2/R3/R4 branch using the current divider rule. Knowing the equivalent resistance of the R2/R3/R4 combination is 50 ohms,

$$I_{234} = I_1\frac{1/50}{1/50 + 1/75}$$

$$I_{234} = (25)\frac{75}{75 + 50}$$

$$I_{234} = (25)\frac{75}{125}$$

Which is the form given by your book.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Vinicius comment. First, find the equivalent resistance of R3 and R4, then add the series resistance of R2. Call this Branch 1. Now find the series resistance of R5 and R6. Call this Branch 2. Now find the parallel resistance of Branch 1 and Branch 2. Add to this R1. You now have the total equivalent resistance of the circuit, and can find the voltage across it (you know the resistance and the current, right?) Now work backwards finding the current splits and voltage drops.